# Is it possible to implente EAP-MSCHAPv2 without Active Directory?

Tags: freeradius

I would like to test 802.1X function for an Ethernet Switch (NAS).
I have a Workstation (Windows 10) and an Ubuntu server : I want to test EAP-MSCHAPv2.

I see a tutorial to configure FreeRADIUS : https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/FreeRADIUS-Active-Directory-Integration-HOWTO

Problem is I don't have a Windows server. Is it possible to test EAP-MSCHAPv2 without it ? How to configure FreeRADIUS ? ... I just want to test a static configuration with one login+password.

Currently my FreeRADIUS works with EAP-MD5 : I already created user profile and NAS config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `MS-CHAP-Use-NTLM-Auth` attribute to `No` in the control list. The `mschap` module will then do the authentication internally, rather than trying to call out to AD.

This is documented more extensively in `raddb/mods-available/mschap`.

For example you could create a user `bob` with password `test` in the `raddb/users` file thus:

```
bob  Cleartext-Password := "test", MS-CHAP-Use-NTLM-Auth := No
```

Note that this attribute must be in the control list, not in the reply list, so appears on the same line as the username.